# Get values at specific altitudes based on unevenly distributed observations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, interpolation

Input data looks like this (pandas DataFrame):

```
     index altitude temperature
0   669084     76.0     NaN
1   669085    190.0   -70.0
2   669086    384.0  -290.0
3   669087    693.0  -430.0
4   669088    883.0  -290.0
5   669089    963.0  -250.0
6   669090    989.0  -250.0
7   669091   1259.0  -380.0
.....
```

It's essentially the result of a single vertical sounding. Measurements are made at "random" altitudes And I need to calculate values at specific altitudes, like 100m, 300m, 500m, 1000m and so on.
.
I presume it should be some form of interpolation, but not sure what's the best approach.

What is the best practice for that using **python**, **numpy** and **pandas**?

Comment: How do you deal with NaNs

Comment: will be hard to calculate temperature for altitude 100 since altitude 76 is `NaN`. Can't interpolate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `reindex` & `interpolate`

First we set `altitude` as index so we can reindex for every "whole" altitude number.

Then we interpolate temperature between the measurements:

*notice, in this case we cannot calculate for measurement `100` since altitude `76` is `NaN`:*

```
min_alt = df['altitude'].min().astype(int)
max_alt = df['altitude'].max().astype(int)+1

newdf = df.set_index('altitude').reindex(range(min_alt, max_alt)).reset_index()

newdf['index'] = newdf['index'].ffill()

newdf['temperature'].interpolate(inplace=True)
newdf['temperature'].interpolate(limit_direction='backward', inplace=True)
```

**Output**

```
      altitude     index  temperature
0           76  669084.0   -70.000000
1           77  669084.0   -70.000000
2           78  669084.0   -70.000000
3           79  669084.0   -70.000000
4           80  669084.0   -70.000000
...        ...       ...          ...
1179      1255  669090.0  -378.074074
1180      1256  669090.0  -378.555556
1181      1257  669090.0  -379.037037
1182      1258  669090.0  -379.518519
1183      1259  669091.0  -380.000000

[1184 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

Then if we check the values at 300m, 500m, and 1000m:

```
newdf.query('altitude.isin([300,500,100])')
```

**Output**

```
     altitude     index  temperature
224       300  669085.0  -194.742268
424       500  669086.0  -342.556634
924      1000  669090.0  -255.296296
```

We can see that `temperature` is interpolated.